# AIMMS constraint specification with same variable

Tags: aimms

In [AIMMS](http://www.aimms.com/), how do I do the following:

This is my constraint:

[image]

Which I'm trying to put into an AIMMS constraint:

[image]

Clearly, there is a contradiction:

In the mathematical summation, we sum (e.g. in the second summation expression) from `j=1,...,p-1` and we have `p=1,...,P` of such constraints.

In AIMMS this translates to: `sum[p | ord(p) <= ord(p) - 1, ... ]` which clearly doesn't make any sense.

How can I make `p=1,...,P` constraints (predefined set) where I have to use the value of `p` in the definition (equation) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AIMMS formulation I don't see the j index used anywhere that is used in the mathematical notation.

As far as I can see, it is just a matter of declaring an additional index j in the same set for which p is already an index and use this index j the same way it is used in the mathematical notation.

You can see the AIMMS blog (http://blog.aimms.com) for some information about using multiple indices in the same set.